# How do I integrate : $∫\frac{\log(x)dx}{(1+x)}?$

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried this method.
Taking $t=x+1$ .Then $dt=dx$ so upper part becomes $\log(t-1)dt/t$  multiply by $t-1$ above and below take $\log(t-1)$ as m so $dm =1/t-1$  noting this after simplifying we get sum of two integrals mdm and  $-\log(x)/x^2+x$  . First integral follows easily for second using by parts and setting $logx$ as first function we get $-\log(x)(x^3/3+x^2/2)-\int(1/(x(x^3/3+x^2/2))$ this can be easily further simplified to get the final solution by taking signs accordingly and resubstitute $\log(x)=m$ .

A shorter and more simplified method would be very helpful.

Comment: learn correct typesetting !

Comment: You might want to check your calculation. I think that $\frac{\log x}{x+1}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: applying by parts could be useful

Comment: Do you perhaps have any limits?

Comment: If you want the indefinite integral you will need the polylogarithm function $Li_2(x)$